# Angular DI: Injecting a value token into factory provider

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

Is it possible to inject an InjectionToken into a factory provider:

Currently, I've coded that:

```
export const HOST_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>("host");

let configDataServiceFactory = (userService: UserService, host: string) => {
    return new Config("host", 8080, userService.getUser(), userService.getPasswd());
};

export let configDataServiceProvider =
{
    provide: CONFIG_API,
    useFactory: configDataServiceFactory,
    deps: [UserService, HOST_TOKEN]
};
```

Into my module:

```
@NgModule(
  providers: [
    {provide: HOST_TOKEN, useValue: "allianz-host"},
    configDataServiceProvider
  ]
)
```

Nevertheless, angular is injecting on `configDataServiceProvider` value `"host"`, instead of `"host-allianz"`

Any ideas?

Comment: I think this should work correctly. Maybe it is because you don't use the variable `host` but a hardcoded string `"host"` as a first argument when calling the Config constructor?!

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can do that using `@Inject` decorator like below, which will help you to extract the relevant dependency from DI container.

```
let configDataServiceFactory = (userService: UserService, @Inject(HOST_TOKEN) host: string) => {
    return new Config(host, 8080, userService.getUser(), userService.getPasswd());
};
```

---

You can also consider below option as well. Basically all registered `InjectionToken`'s would be available to retrieve from application `Injector`, that can be achieve by calling `get` method over `injector` instance and pass `InjectorToken` name.

```
export const HOST_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<string>("host");

let configDataServiceFactory = (userService: UserService, injector: Injector) => {
    let host = injector.get(HOST_TOKEN); //retrieved token from injector
    return new Config(host, 8080, userService.getUser(), userService.getPasswd());
};

export let configDataServiceProvider =
{
    provide: CONFIG_API,
    useFactory: configDataServiceFactory,
    deps: [UserService, Injector]
};
```

[**Docs Here**](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken)

Comment: when use APP_INITIALIZER  at root level, it is waiting to resolve the promise, but i need to inject one service inside a child module with custom factory and also it should wait to resolve, but actually it not calling method itself 

export const CONFIG = new InjectionToken<string>('');

export function initializeApp(mfService: MFEService): () => 
// not reaching here
Promise<void> {
  return () => mfService.initialise();
}

providers:[
 {
      provide: CONFIG ,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [MFEService],
    },
]

any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console? it would be great if you provide me a stackblitz, I can try play around with it, to fix the same.