# Use Angular Value Provider Values In Factory Function Inside AppModule

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-auth-oidc-client

I'm attempting to access some value providers inside a factory function inside the AppModule (OidcConfigService below).  Normally, inside components, I can just have the values I'm trying to get via constructor injection using @Inject('PROVIDER_NAME').  In this case, it's just a factory function so there's no constructor for me to get my values.  You can see my attempt at getting the values inside the OidcConfigService provider, but these are just failed attempts.

AppModule (the function configureAuth at the bottom is where I'm trying to have the values sent)

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, NgModule, Input, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
//Angular modules
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
//Third-party modules
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AuthModule, OidcConfigService, LogLevel, PublicEventsService, EventTypes } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { ConvertDatetimeToLocalPipe } from 'src/app/pipes/datetime/convert-datetime-to-local-pipe';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
//Components
<<LIST OF COMPONENTS>>

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
     <<LIST OF COMPONENTS>>
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule,
    AuthModule.forRoot(),
    CommonModule,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [
    RequestService,
    ConvertDatetimeToLocalPipe,
    OidcConfigService,
    {
        provide: [APP_INITIALIZER, { provide: AUTH_URL, useValue: AppConfig }],
        useFactory: configureAuth,
        deps: [OidcConfigService, @Inject('AUTH_URL')],
        multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(private readonly eventService: PublicEventsService) {
      this.eventService
          .registerForEvents()
          .pipe(filter((notification) => notification.type === EventTypes.ConfigLoaded))
          .subscribe((config) => {
              console.log('ConfigLoaded', config);
          });
  }
}

export function configureAuth(oidcConfigService: OidcConfigService) {
  return () =>
      oidcConfigService.withConfig({
        //stsServer: this._authUrl,
        stsServer: 'http://localhost:5999',
        redirectUrl: `${window.location.origin}/postloginloading`,
        clientId: 'admin_web_app_client',
        responseType: 'code',
        scope: 'openid profile role ReviewApi UserApi',
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin,
        forbiddenRoute: '/forbidden',
        unauthorizedRoute: '/unauthorized',
        silentRenew: true,
        silentRenewUrl: `${window.location.origin}/silent-renew.html`,
        historyCleanupOff: true,
        autoUserinfo: true,
        logLevel: LogLevel.Warn,
        maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: 10,
        storage: localStorage //If not working, change back to sessionStorage
      });
}
```

main.ts (these are the values I'm trying to access)

```
  const providers = [
    { provide: 'BASE_URL', useFactory: getBaseUrl, deps: [] },
    { provide: 'AUTH_URL', useValue: 'http://localhost:5999' },
    { provide: 'REVIEWAPI_URL', useValue: 'http://localhost:5101' },
    { provide: 'USERAPI_URL', useValue: 'http://localhost:5105' }
  ];

  platformBrowserDynamic(providers).bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try injecting the `Injector` as a dependency (i.e. `deps: [OidcConfigService, Injector]`) and use `injector.get(AUTH_URL)` to resolve the value of `AUTH_URL` at runtime

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742028/angular-di-injecting-a-value-token-into-factory-provider

Comment: Wow, your first comment is exactly what I needed!  Feel free to post as an actual answer and I'll mark it as solved.